# CSS Applying specific rule for a specific monitor resolution with only CSS is posible?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a design with a `width;1010px` this design have two Arrow for a slideshow "left" and "right" and are out of the box (`width:1010px` div container), in an absolute position.

```
.showcase-arrow-next
{
    right: -40px;
    top:150px;
    background-position: -70px 0px;
}
```

so I would like to know if it's posible to declare a rule for specific monitor resolution, actually for ipad resolution 1024x728, I would like to position my arrows inside of the 1010px container when the monitor is 1024x728, I know how to do this with prototype, jquery, javascript alike solutions, But I don't know if it's posible to resolve this problem with only css approach.

thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [CSS3 Media Query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to apply conditional styles to devices with a specific size:

```
<style>
    @media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {   
        .showcase-arrow-next {
            right: -40px;
            top: 150px;
        }
    }    
</style>
```

You can also detect the orientation of the device (Portrait vs. Landscape) by using the **'orientation' media feature**, which can be combined like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
    and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* iPad Portrait Mode */

    .showcase-arrow-next {
        ...
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
    and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* iPad Landscape Mode */

    .showcase-arrow-next {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it's there a way to test it in my own monitor? or do I have to use another device?? cause I resize my firefox browser in 1024x728 pixel and I don't see any change :P...

Comment: To test in a desktop browser, you'll need to adjust the media queries, changing `device-width` to `width` and removing the `orientation` detection. Here's a [simplified jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8WdL3/2/embedded/result/), simulating the iPad's screen size of 768 x 1024. Resize your browser window and you'll notice the background color change from green to red.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and you should search the web for "Responsive web design" and read about [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Something like this would be what you´re looking for;

```
@media handheld and (width: 1024px) {
  // add your CSS rules here
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, I will do it, and I gave the answer to @rjb only cause he responses before of you, thanks anyway.