# how to hide a div when the width in pixels change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is it possible to hide a div when the width changes? I know you can do it with bootstrap but I need to somehow do it without it. i need it to display:none when increase and it needs to display:block when it is returned to 612px

```
<div id="grid" style="width:612px"></div>
```

Comment: How does its size even change? Is the user able to do it, does it happen upon an event or what exactly happens?

Comment: sorry, the click event is somewhere in kendo-ui javascript. dont know how to access it

Comment: I am assuming you want to use media queries via css? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772656/css-applying-specific-rule-for-a-specific-monitor-resolution-with-only-css-is-po

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to write something that checks the width and shows/hides it based on that width:

```
function checkGridWidth() {
    var gridWidth = $('#grid').width();
    if(gridWidth == 612){
        $('#grid').show();
    }else{
        $('#grid').hide();
    }
};
```

You'll probably want to check the width on document ready as well as when certain events happen, such as window width resizes or maybe clicks?? not sure what could affect the width:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkGridWidth();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  checkGridWidth();
});

$('#someElement').click(function() {
  checkGridWidth();
});
```

**EDIT** 
Based on comments from OP, the need is for an event handler that will allow the #grid to be collapsed when another element is expanded...

See: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/splitter/api
And: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/splitter/events

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                function collapseOtherSplitter() {
                    splitter.size(indexOfPane, 0);// where indexOfPane is the index of the pane you want to collapse
                }

                function onExpand(e) {
                    collapseOtherSplitter();
                }

                // One of your top, horizontal splitters that you want to collapse when the vertical splitter expands:
                var splitter = $("#horiz-splitter").kendoSplitter({
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    panes: [
                        { collapsible: true, size: "50%" },
                    ],
                });


                // Your bottom, vertical splitter
                $("#vertical-splitter").kendoSplitter({
                    orientation: "vertical",
                    panes: [
                        { collapsible: true, size: "100px" },
                    ],
                    expand: onExpand,
                });
            });
```

Comment: I was trying to find the click event for the splitter, when the right pane becomes full width

Comment: I'm not following... do you have a second question related to a Kendo Splitter?

Comment: No, sorry for being unclear. I am using the kendo splitter. Right and left pane only. On the left is a map. On the right is a chart and directly underneath is a grid. When I click on the splitter to make the right pane full screen I need to remove the grid. Reason is the chart needs to adjust it's height so it will look proportional

Answer (score 2):

You cannot listen for a width change, instead of that you can **add a new event listener** (different from the kendo-ui event handler) for the same element and check the width. In that case you can show or hide the element depending on the current width.

Comment: I was trying to find the click event for the splitter, when the right pane becomes full width

Comment: demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/splitter/index

Comment: Then you can use one of the events for that splitter:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/splitter/events

Maybe it will work with expand or resize.

e.g. 
`function onExpand(e) {
  this.element[0].style.display = 'none';
}
`